# How to apply condition on rows that have the same ID?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like :

```
df= [ ID  child_ID  STATUS1  
      123  11        OK    
      123  22        KO 
      123  23        OK 
      124  56        OK  
      124  45        OK
```

I want to get a final status by ID,if one of the child_id is KO it means that my finalstatus is KO 
so i want a dataframe like :

```
f= [      ID  Child_ID STATUS1  Statusfinal
          123  11       OK       KO
          123  22       KO       KO
          123  23       OK       KO
          124  56       OK       OK
          124  45       OK       OK
```

how can i do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
g = df.groupby('ID')
df['Statusfinal'] = np.where((g['STATUS1'].transform(lambda x: x.eq('KO').any())), 'KO',df['STATUS1'])
```

output

```
df['Statusfinal']
Out[2]: 
0    KO
1    KO
2    KO
3    OK
4    OK
Name: Statusfinal, dtype: object
```

Or:

As pointed out in the comment by piRSquared:

```
df['Statusfinal'] = np.where(df.STATUS1.eq('KO').groupby(df.ID).transform('any'), 'KO', df['STATUS1'])
```

Comment: I'd leverage the use of the string functions that `transform` can utilize.  This avoids the `lambda` and probably speeds things up.  `df.STATUS1.eq('KO').groupby(df.ID).transform('any')`.  However, this requires some prep work as you can see from how I evaluated `df.STATUS1.eq('KO')` before my `groupby`

Comment: @piRSquared It seems to be a more elegant method than `lambda`. Thanks for this :)

Comment: I TRIED the 'df['Statusfinal'] = np.where(df.STATUS1.eq('KO').groupby(df.ID).transform('any'), 'KO', df['STATUS1'])'  it works fine thanks